# Extract individual audio tracks from an audio DVD

Tags: macos, audio, dvd

I would like to extract the audio from a concert DVD to audio files, e.g. *mp3* or *aac*. How can I do this using *free* tools - I know there are a couple of pay options available, but I would like to use free tools if possible.

Please note that I don't want to playback/record the audio, but extract it directly from the DVD. The DVD has a stereo PCM track.

Ideally, I want to end up with one audio file per chapter/track.

I know how to use the command line, so scripts are welcome as well. Homebrew is installed as well.

Update:
I've read the following two guides for using VLC, but they seem to be outdated, the screens seem to have changed in recent versions of VLC. Especially the *Convert/Save* menu item is now named *Convert/Stream* and the screen seems to have changed considerably.

- https://wiki.videolan.org/Extract_audio
- http://www.wikihow.com/Rip-DVD-Audio-to-MP3-Using-VLC-Media-Player

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77031/what-software-can-rip-high-quality-audio-from-a-dvd-losslessly-if-possible for more options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it in the end, since I was unsuccessful using VLC. In some cases, I ended up with static in the file, and the command line instructions from some of the guides I posted in the question failed, since the commands seem to have changed.

I also tried tools like `ffmpeg`, but didn't get any usable output from that either.

What finally worked were the instructions found here: http://www.essl.de/wp/2008/01/28/rip-audio-from-a-dvd/

First, I installed the following tools using *Homebrew*:

```
$ brew install lame
$ brew install mplayer
```

Secondly, to get a list of the chapters of the DVD, I used this with the DVD in the drive of my MacBook Pro:

```
$ mplayer -identify -frames 0 dvd://1 | grep "_CHAPTERS"
```

This will print the number of chapters per title, in my case, I noticed that there are 13  tracks in the first title.

To get the available audio channels listed, I used a similar command:

```
$ mplayer -identify -frames 0 dvd://1 | grep "aid"
```

This showed that the channel with the *aid* value of *160* had the DVD's stereo track (*lpcm*).

To extract the audio and convert it to MP3, I wrote the following reusable script (`ripaudio.sh`), which extracts and converts one chapter:

```
#!/bin/bash

CHAPTER=$1
AID=$2

mplayer -benchmark -vc null -vo null dvd://1 -chapter $CHAPTER-$CHAPTER -aid $AID -ao pcm:fast:file=$CHAPTER.wav && lame --preset standard $CHAPTER.wav $CHAPTER.mp3 && rm $CHAPTER.wav
```

Make the script executable using

```
$ chmod +x ripaudio.sh
```

Call it to extract the first chapter using

```
$ ./ripaudio 1 160
```

What this basically does is this:

- MPlayer extracts the audio track with id *160* of the first track and saves it to a file called `1.wav`. The video part of the track is ignored
- The *Lame* encoder is used to encode the `.wav` file into an MP3 file called `1.mp3`. Lame's *standard* preset is used.
- The file `1.wav` is deleted.
- The commands are chained using the `&&` operator to make sure they only run when the previous one succeeds. The whole `mplayer etc.` command needs to be on a single line.

To convert all of the chapters, the following `for` loop can be used:

```
for i in {1..13}; do ./ripaudio.sh $i 160 ; done
```

This will take a while, but once it's done, you'll end up with one MP3 file per chapter in the current directory.

The script can easily be adapted to use something like *flac* instead of *lame* for the encoding. Place the script in your user's `~/bin` folder to call it from any location.

While this took a while to research and doesn't have a fancy UI, it was the best method I've found.

Comment: great answer, thanks! also, unless you are waiting for other answers, please mark this as accepted

Comment: Nearly every command in this answer outputs `Can't init Apple Remote` on High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLC:

1. Open VLC.
2. Press ⌘D and insert disc or select VIDEO_TS folder.
3. Select the box for Streaming/Saving.
4. Click Settings.
5. In Streaming and Transcoding Options, select File and browse to a location to save the file.
6. In Transcoding Options, uncheck Video and check Audio, then select a format (mp3) and bitrate.
7. Click OK, then Open. It will begin transcoding.

Comment: How can I automate this for extracting all tracks, with every DVD chapter into its own file? From what I can see, the above will output a single file.

Comment: On a DVD Audio, there should be no VIDEO_TS but AUDIO_TS.

Comment: Won't this process result in a single, large audio file for the entire movie, rather than separate audio track for each DVD chapter?

Comment: I tried this with VIDEO_TS as stated and then with AUDIO_TS.  Either one produced file type of "MPEG transport stream data" which Amadeus Pro was able to open but showed it as less than 39 millseconds of silence (even though it was 107MB).